# JQuery and units

Tags: jquery

I am playing with an animated menu and have done everything with CSS to keep the layout fluid, that is to say, I have everything in em units and scaling the text size will scale my menu accordingly.

Animating this menu with jQuery, however, the natural units are px, so that the animation works with the normal font size, but its layout breaks at other sizes...

Is there a way to work with other units (in particular em) in jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the unit at the end of a jquery calculation or number by typing

```
+ 'em'
```

When doing fluid layouts it's much easier to work with pixels especially when you are involving jquery because of, as you mentioned, it's use of pixel units rather than anything else.

Building truly fluid layouts with jquery, css and html will require some CSS tricks such as using positioning absolute with inner padding to keep things in place without having to use jquery calculations.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way of getting the size in px of 1em in the current font size?

Comment: the easiest way would be to set the font-size in the body first to 62.5% and then again to whatever size you want throughout the CSS. That way 1.0em = 10px, 1.1em = 11px and so on. They are both based on different things, pixels being based on screen pixels and em is based relative to the font size, so there's no 100% way to convert one to the other.

Comment: I see... What does, for example, .css("left") return? The em value in px?

Comment: jquery will only ever return a value in pixels.